# Add links to data in HTML table Created using PHP and a MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to pull data from a table in PHPmyadmin and convert it to an HTML table based on some customer form input which filters out unneeded rows. The code below does that fine. The issue is that two of my columns need to contain links.

It would be easy enough to use PHP to change the table data into the link using a `strtolower()` and `str_replace()` to remove spaces, then concatinating the "www.website.com/" and the ".html". But I'm using a foreach loop to get all of the rows that I need and I don't know how to only alter one value per row.

I have tried using "Broswer Display Transformations" and "Input Transformations" in PHPmyadmin, but that only seems to affect the data in PHPmyadmin and not when I access the data via PHP.

My current code:

```
//* Code for Table
$query = "SELECT $searchFields FROM `hose_reels` $searchPhrase ORDER BY `model` ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query);

if ($row[$key] != "0") {

echo '<table width="100%" border="1" class="table"><tr>';
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
foreach ($row AS $key => $value) {
    $key = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $key));
    echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
$result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row AS $key => $value) {
            $row['$key'] = $value;
            echo "<td>$row[$key]</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "<p>No results match your selection. Please broaden your search.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Do you know the `column names` for each row? can I have some example output or a row or two?

Comment: I do know the column names. I call them out earlier in the code with by establishing the `$searchFields` variable which states what columns to include.  The output is a simple html table that shows nine columns and the corresponding fields from each row (if these rows were selected in the form).

Comment: This is the first 2 rows `<table width="100%" border="1" class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Series</th>
      <th>Hose ID (in)</th>
      <th>Hose OD (in)</th>
      <th>Inlet (in)</th>
      <th>Outlet (in)</th>
      <th>Hose Length (ft)</th>
      <th>Pressure (PSI)</th>
      <th>Max Temp (°F)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4400 OLP</td>
      <td>4000</td>
      <td>0.250</td>
      <td>0.475</td>
      <td>0.375</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>150</td>
   </tr>
</table>`

Comment: I would suggest adding a loop counter, and every time the loop counter hits the numbers you want to put a link on, write an if statement to do so. after each `td`, increment the loop counter `$loopCount++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `<a>` tag in your php code. Below is the code. One more thing you have error in `echo "<td>$row[$key]</td>";` line . it prints `<td>$row[$key]</td>` not the result you are fetching from DB.

```
echo '<table width="100%" border="1" class="table"><tr>';
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$i = 1;
foreach ($row AS $key => $value) {
    $key = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $key));
       if($i == 1 || $i ==3){
         echo "<th><a href='".key ."'" . $key . "</a></th>";
       }else{
         echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
       }
     $i++;
    }
echo "</tr>";
$result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
$j =1;
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row AS $key => $value) {
            $row['$key'] = $value;
            if($i == 1 || $i ==3){
               echo "<td><a href='".$row[$key]."'".$row[$key]."</a></td>";
            }else{
              echo "<td>$row[$key]</td>";
            }
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I don't want every cell to be a link. Only the cells in the first and second columns. About the echo error: I assume you mean that I should write  `echo "<td>" . $row[$key] . "</td>";` instead. But it works fine as is.